# SSIS - pivoting duplicate values in multiple records

Tags: ssis, pivot

I have a situation like this:

```
ID  TYPE    TIMESTAMP
1   A       22/06/2015 03:55:02
1   A       22/06/2015 03:55:05
1   B       22/06/2015 03:55:10
```

Of course if i try to pivot SISS gives an error telling that there is a duplicate value in the TYPE for that ID; so I thought it would be nice to have a result like this:

```
ID  occurrence  A                       B
1   1           22/06/2015 03:55:02     22/06/2015 03:55:10
1   2           22/06/2015 03:55:05
```

It would be also nice if the fist occurrence would be filled with the earlier timestamps of the events (A and B), but I think this will be done just by ordering correctly.

Can this be done?

Comment: Is there a reasonable upper bound on how many columns could be generated by the duplicates? Where does your source data come from?

Comment: It's the log of SSIS. What I call TYPE are the events of the log:
OnPreExecute;
OnPostExecute;
OnError;
OnTaskFailed;
PackageStart;
PackageEnd.

As you can see the modalities are few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use ROW_NUMBER to create the "Occurrence" column and pivot the data based on Type

```
SELECT  * 
FROM (  
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID], [Type] ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) Occurrence  
        FROM    Test
) t
PIVOT
(       MAX([TimeStamp])
        FOR [Type] IN ([A],[B])
) p
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39091/2)